# Use of Me2SOI/NaOH

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

[image]

In **V** triazole ($\ce{N^1}$) will substitute -Cl group. However from **V** to **W**, I don't get what $\ce{Me2SO+I-}$ in presence of base will do. Any hint? I also wish to know how to *guess* the reactions, in case one don't know them.

Comment: I think there is a small but crucial error in the question. The reagent should be Me3SOI. The protons on the Me group are acidic due to the adjacent S + centre.

Comment: See: [Johnson–Corey–Chaykovsky reaction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johnson%E2%80%93Corey%E2%80%93Chaykovsky_reaction)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Trimethyl sulfoxonium iodide (and the closely related trimethylsulfonium iodide) form a methylene epoxide from a carbonyl. The protons on the Me groups are activated due to the proximity of the S+ centre. Deprotonation, more often with NaH, gives a nucleophilic species that attacks the carbonyl group. The resulting O- attacks the incoming methylene-S centre displacing DMSO to give the epoxide.

Comment: You showed me the path, how to think that. That was the kind of answer I was expecting.